# Maven build war modules into an ear

Tags: maven, packaging, maven-ear-plugin

I have a maven project with ear packaging, including two webModule and dependencies to maven WAR package. Whenever I build changes, I need first to manually build the two war via "maven clean install" and in the end I build the ear always via "maven clean install".

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>it.test.esempio.fe</groupId>
        <artifactId>ESEMPIO_FE_PTL_PARENT</artifactId>
        <version>1.32.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>ESEMPIO_FE_TEMA_COMPLETO</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- START: PROJECT DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.test.esempio.fe</groupId>
            <artifactId>ESEMPIO_FE_TEMA_COMPLETO_STATICO</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.test.esempio.fe</groupId>
            <artifactId>ESEMPIO_FE_TEMA_COMPLETO_DINAMICO</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- END: PROJECT DEPENDENCIES -->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>6</version>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>it.test.esempio.fe</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ESEMPIO_FE_TEMA_COMPLETO_DINAMICO</artifactId>
                            <bundleFileName>ESEMPIO_FE_TEMA_COMPLETO_DINAMICO.war</bundleFileName>
                            <contextRoot>wps/ESEMPIO_FE_TEMA_COMPLETO_DINAMICO</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>it.test.esempio.fe</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ESEMPIO_FE_TEMA_COMPLETO_STATICO</artifactId>
                            <bundleFileName>ESEMPIO_FE_TEMA_COMPLETO_STATICO.war</bundleFileName>
                            <contextRoot>wps/ESEMPIO_FE_TEMA_COMPLETO_STATICO</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Is it possible to make in way to automatically build the 2 war and the ear with only one build command?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you show your full pom files please...

Comment: Edited, thanks for interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

Create an appropriate directory structure:

```
 +-- root (pom.xml)
      +--- war-module1 (pom.xml)
      +--- war-module2 (pom.xml)
      +--- ear-module (pom.xml)
```

Put the list of existing modules into the root pom (modules list)..and define appropriate dependencies between the modules. Now you can simply build everything in one go from root via:

```
mvn clean package
```

or if you need:

```
mvn clean install
```